# VS-Code can't find allready referenced package

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

So I have following Problem with VS-Code and the "Haskell - language environment":

I use cabal as building tool. On my project I have included a github repo as "build-depends" (with its respective cabal.project file...). When I import a module from the repo it says:

> "Could not load module ... It is a member of the hidden package ...
> Perhaps you need to add ... to the build-depends in your .cabal file."

Although I added the package to the cabal file.
Furthermore "cabal build" will work without any problems...
So my feeling is that this is a problem with VS-Code and its respective error highlighting... -> what am I missing?

cabal.project:

```
source-repository-package
  type: git
  location: ...

packages: ./... .cabal
```

... .cabal:

```
cabal-version:      2.4
name:               ...
version:            0.1.0.0

extra-source-files: CHANGELOG.md

executable HaskellProject
    main-is:          Main.hs

    build-depends:          base ^>=4.14.3.0
                        ,   my-repo
                       
    hs-source-dirs:     app
    default-language:   Haskell2010
```

the github repo:

```
.../my-repo
|-Setup.hs
|-my-repo.cabal
```

my-repo.cabal

```
cabal-version:      2.4
name:               my-repo
version:            0.1.0.0
Build-type:         Simple
author:             Momentum93
maintainer:         ...
Library

  build-depends:      base ^>=4.14.3.0
  exposed-modules:
    ...
```

Setup.hs

```
import Distribution.Simple
main = defaultMain
```

Comment: I see nothing in your `build-depends` except for `base`?

Comment: @HTNW I assume you refer to: my-repo.cabal -> this is the repo my project should depend on (like you can see in: "... .cabal") so it makes no diference (for this example) if the library in the github repo depends on anything...

Comment: Oh oops. Guess I should get some new eyes...